# Wordpress AJAX call width admin-ajax.php returns empty result

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a `ACF` custom field with a selectbox and now I want to return the selected options with AJAX, so in my `functions.php`-file I wrote this:

```
function get_movies(){

$posts = get_field('choose_movies'); 

    if( $posts ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): ?>
        <div class="movie-item">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>">
                <div class="movie-wrapper">
                    <?php $image = get_field('movie_image', $p->ID); ?>
                        <div class="movie-image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>')"></div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <p><?php the_field('movie_title', $p->ID); ?></p>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
<?php }

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_movies', 'get_movies');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_movies','get_movies');
```

and in my js file when I call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: {
    action: "get_movies"
  },
  success: function(data){
     console.log('DATA: ', data)
  }
```

the `data` is empty e.g. gives me `0` - can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

OK, so I added the following lines to pass the postID:

```
function get_movies( $post ){
   global $wpdb;
   $pid = $post->ID;
   $posts = the_field('choose_movies', $post->ID);
   ...
}
```

but still, `$posts` is empty - this is really getting a pain in the a..

Comment: What does `var_dump( $posts );` return? Also, you need to add `wp_die();` at the end of your `get_movies()` function.

Comment: Hmm ok, actually `var_dump( $posts );` returns nothing :-/

Comment: Then that's why :P You need to figure out why `get_field()` doesn't return any posts, fix that and you're good to go.

Comment: You have a context problem. There is no current post when WordPress does AJAX processing. So, you need to specify a post id in get_field().

Comment: @magenta like how?

Comment: Going by your code I am assuming your selectbox is a acf relationship type field getting data from another post type. But what is the post context for the selectbox? What I mean by that is for which post are you trying to get the selected movies? If it is on single view then you should also pass post id in your ajax call.

Comment: @FahamShaikh Yes the selectbox is a afc relationship and the post is a custom post type. How do I pass the post_id to the ajax call?

Comment: @ST80, you can either set the value in a hidden input field and use from there in your js file or you can use the global $post object. The former is more suitable approach and you should also consider few standard practices like nonce and passing data as json instead of html.

Comment: Your understanding of how AJAX works in WordPress plugins is incorrect. Please read https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. The example code shows how to correctly pass parameters to the server side AJAX function. Observe the use of $_POST['whatever'].